# Django admin panel search bar not work (Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains)

Tags: python, django

I have in models

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sats_balance = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=15, default=pin_generator)
    pin_saved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and in the wallet app admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
class WalletAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['user']
```

the search bar has exist  but when I search for any user I got this error

```
raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))
```

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the field on the user model you want to search, for example:

```py
class WalletAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['user__first_name', 'user__last_name']
```

Comment: Thanks it worked when i did ` search_fields = ['user__username']`